# How to redirect a user from a Firebase Deeplink Website

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Let's say I have a link like https://google.com/my_deeep_link?invitation_id=1234 which on iOS I process with:

```
let dynamicLinksDomain = "my.page.link"
let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: dynamicLinksDomain)
linkBuilder.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "com.abc.xyz")
linkBuilder.shorten { (url: URL?, warnings: [String]?, error: Error?) in

}
```

Which generates a link like https://my.page.link/some_unique_id
If a user presses on this link (Notes, Conversation, etc.) it opens my app and I can grab the `invitation_id` after Firebase has handled the Deep Link and it has turned the deep link into the original URL.

Now in the scenario that the user copies the link instead of pressing on it and puts it in the Safari (iOS), it does not open the app, instead it displays the website (which is contained in the shortened link).
On this website I have access to the requests' referrer which is `my.page.link` however I can not grab the `unique_id` identifier from the referrer.

Ideally the website could have access to https://my.page.link/some_unique_id so it can display a button saying "Click me to accept the invitation" and pressing this button would open the link in the app as expected.

Is there any way to do this? Because I don't want to send the deep links off to the database or anything and also I would have no way of knowing which link to grab from the DB as the user won't authenticate on the web.

Thank you

Comment: Why not put some_unique_id in the fallback URL as well?

Comment: Well I can‘t put some_unique_id into the fallback, because the identifier is being generated when shorting the link

Comment: Ah I see - I would pass the invite code as part of the link parameter and the fallback parameter, rather than relying on the generated part of the shortlink url.

Comment: yeah that makes more sense. I‘ll think about it when I get back to this part of the app